# Laravel relationship on a column that is an array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am rather stuck (or not stuck, as I could go and solve this simply with foreach) with a problem I am facing.

I have database where I have a model that should have a relation to another one. No problem here. However, that relation is defined in a column that is an array. I sadly cant change that. Is there any way to still get the corresponding relation of hasMany etc?

Or is my only choice to get all entries of my model and then go over foreach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can setup a Model function, like `public function things(){ return Thing::whereIn('id', $this->column_with_array_of_ids)->get(); }`, then `Model::first()->things()` would return the related `Thing` instances, but **you cannot use the `hasMany()` relationship**.

Comment: As Tim Lewis said, you cannot, you are losing any Eloquent advantage about it, for example [`sync`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) or simply using `$model->hasManyRelation()->something()` as you do not have `hasManyRelation` available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70257317/14344959 see here I share sample example in answer